# Wix installer: Wrong copyright property value

Tags: wix

In my Wix installer project (.wixproj), I am setting Product properties like **Manufacturer** and **Version**.

Once the setup.exe is created, in windows explorer, if I right click on this exe and see properties under Detail tab, it is showing wrong value in the Copyright property. For example: I have set "Abc Ltd" as value of **Manufacturer** property but the Copyright is showing "Alpha Ltd"

What am I doing wrong?